# Is it okay to take a different route after a Uk visa refusal

Tags: uk

I would like to say little about myself. First I'm a Master's graduate in science from a well esteemed university in London and was working for a tier 1 consultancy company based out in London for almost 2 years. My husband and I are India origin but he currently holds a British citizenship.

I had applied for a dependant spousal visa; unfortunately it got refused twice due to financial requirement issues. However my husband has enough income to support me in the UK. we did provide enough supportive documents to prove his self employment and submitted all tax papers.

Since it's been a nightmare we are deciding to take a different route - maybe try for myself an employment visa with my last company and have them sponsor me back to UK. Or is it best to do a visiting visa at this point. We did seek advise for a immigration solicitor they have told us to wait for 6 months before making a re application for a partner visa. Due to his business he is unable to come down even if he could he wouldn't be able to make it for a long trip.

Just wondering is visiting him for a 6 months is a good move at this stage ? Please advice me on the same thanks a lot .

Comment: If you have been refused twice on a spouse visa, so  (as they say in Vegas) your cards are out. I agree with your solicitor, you should apply again for a spouse visa until you get it right.  Your question about a visit visa is wholly down to opinion. I wouldn't, but the next guy might say it's fine.  Close voting as 'opinion-based', sorry.

Comment: Although Gayot is an honourable exception, it's pretty unlikely that random strangers on the internet are going to give you better advice than a solicitor.

Comment: You think they would believe you were just coming to visit after two refusals for a spousal visa???